# implementing sockets in Android kotlin

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin

I have an android app and API, I want to let the api know if the android app is online/ offline. I was thinking about doing this with Sockets, have a socket connection open between the android app and the api and that way we can determine if the app is online or offline.

I am going to implement this in my android library in Kotlin.

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 29
```

what is the best way to implement sockets in Android kotlin. Any examples or links would be very helpful

Also if you think there is any other approach to achieve online/offline do let me know.

Thanks
R

Comment: As we dont know what your API is able to we can not advice.

Comment: ohh so this depends on API?, I was thinking this would be generic

Comment: Well tell: how to tell your API that i go offline?